# Opposite of a blurred memory

Tags: meaning, word-choice, antonyms

I am looking for an antonym for a "blurred memory" in context of photos. Can't get what it would be:

1. Sharp photo
2. Clear photo
3. Vivid photo
4. Distinct photo
5. Smh else?

The context is as follows: "We all have memories, many of them get blurred over time. Photography helps us here so we can keep a *sharp* picture instead."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes the adjective *acute* is used to describe vision, but it's not clear that it fits your scenario.

Comment: ... finely etched (pardoning the mixed metaphor)

Comment: If it's a slogan, something like: *Memories get blurry. Our photos stay sharp.*

Answer (score 1):

Photographs are ***in focus***. Memories are [***vivid***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vivid).

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't a writing advice forum, and this doesn't *technically* give the answer you're looking for (a word), but I think the following would be much better:

> We all have memories, many of them get blurred over time. Photography helps us here by preserving the past, even if our memories can't.

Answer (score 0):

*Photography helps us to **resolve** blurred memories of past events so that they become almost as clear and vivid as they once were.*

***Resolve*** - to distinguish parts or components of (something) that are close together in space or time; to identify or distinguish individually. Of an object initially perceived indistinctly: to become identifiable, esp. as a number of discrete objects. (OED)